# Regular expression that excludes carriage return returns a match with carriage return

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

Consider the following C# code:

```cs
string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\_Temporary\\MyFile.txt");
var reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\"Second\" -- (.+)");
var val = reg.Match(s).Groups[1].Value;
```

or this in VB.NET:

```vb
Dim s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\_Temporary\MyFile.txt")
Dim reg = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("""Second"" -- (.+)")
Dim val = reg.Match(s).Groups(1).Value
```

And the contents of `C:\_Temporary\MyFile.txt`:

> "First" -- here is my first item.
>
> "Second" -- here is my second item.
>
> "Third" -- here is my third item.

If the RegEx meta-character `.` excludes all line-ending characters (and, indeed, is preventing the match from returning the rest of the contents below `"Second" -- here is my second item.`), why is it that `val` ends with a carriage return (`\r`)?

[image]

Comment: Since when does `\r` denote a line break? Oh right, Windows logic. </sass>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's .NET 4.5 Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the `.` is a "Wildcard: Matches any single character except `\n`.

Comment: The `SingleLine` flag controls this behaviour

Comment: I was referencing http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html, specifically "The dot matches a single character, without caring what that character is. The only exception are line break characters.".  I interpreted "line break characters" to mean ALL line break characters.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately not everyone uses the same regex rules.  And .NET decided to only include _the_ line break character `\n`

Comment: @ryanyuyu Javascript has similar regex rules as .NET

Comment: @TomLint No, javascript dotall matches both `\r`, `\n`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll